# Why am I getting different results when using the DATEDIFF function with a different specified interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm running the following queries using the DATEDIFF function using the YEAR and MONTH intervals, but modifying the right side of the query accordingly so that I thought they should be identical.  `dbo.logs` has **2486512** rows.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.logs                  
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, DT, GetDate()) <= 1;

result: 595712

SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.logs                  
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DT, GetDate()) <= 12;

result: 334773
```

Why am I getting such drastically different results?  I would think specifying 12 months would return the same number of rows as 1 year.

Comment: DATEDIFF(MONTH, DT, GetDate()) will give you  month parth

Comment: Please refer to the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 `This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate`. Meaning for `DATEDIFF(YEAR, DT, GetDate()) <= 1` , it includes `DT` = `2018-01-01` till today. where as `DATEDIFF(MONTH, DT, GetDate()) <= 12` only includes `2018-08-01` till today

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF()` doesn't quite do what you expect.  It counts the number of *boundaries* between two date/times.  So, the year difference for both the following is "1":

```
2018-12-31  and   2019-01-01
2018-01-01  and   2019-12-31
```

The month differences vary between 1 and 23.

A much better approach is to use date arithmetic:

```
WHERE DT <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Not only is this more accurate, but it can also take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 0):

It gives year difference only

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2017-02-02', GetDate())  
Result-2
```

It gives month difference only.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2019-02-02', GetDate())
```

Result-5